# WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I get this error "WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: races_attributes"
, when following this http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 on rails 3.

Where Races are a component of Events. This is my models/race.rb:

```
class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event

attr_accessible :name, :unit
end
```

This is my models/event.rb:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :races, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :races

attr_accessible :name, :date, :description, :location_name, :address_one, :address_two, :city, :state, :zip, :active, :races_attributes
end
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`attr_accessible` specifies that you can not mass-assign attributes, using `save` method, for example. So, if you change an attribute that is not defined with `attr_accessible`, you will get a warning because it will not actually be saved in the database.

Comment: I've added all of the attributes that are in the form to each respective attr_accessible

Comment: Whoops, I forgot the event_id one. Dang it!

Answer (score 20):

Shorter than using `attr_accessible`, safer than using `whitelist_attributes`: **attr_protected**

Just indicate the protected attributes, and Rails will infer that all others can be mass-assigned:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :id
end
```

(I always have way more attributes that I want mass-assigned than the ones I want protected.)

Comment: Just for reference, whitelist_attributes can be set in application.rb: `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` in case you want to do a quick hack and not have to modify individual models. Just comment  out the line.